# How to send a Javascript variable to server side?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I must add items to an existing code, but I do not know all the patterns established.
I need to retrieve a value from a numeric field in javascript, store it in a JSP tag variable and submit it to a Java method.
I know javascript is client side and the server-side Java.

This is a numeric field "ZONE" whose value must be recovered for a loop

The added code is input "ZONE", the Action buton "ADD_ELEMENT_LISTE_OUVERTE_1" and the variable and loop "zone".

thanks !

JSP-side code:

```
<popo:form>

    <div class="left">
    nombre de colonnes <input type="number" id="zone"  name="zone" class="text" maxlength="25" valeur="" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <%controller.getContext().getInteger(ListeOuverteContributionDetailController.ZONE) =%>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getZoneJS() {
                var zone=(parseInt(document.form.elements["zone"].value));
                if (zone != null ){
                    return zone;
                }                                        
            }
        </script>

        <popo:action name="ADD_ELEMENT_LISTE_OUVERTE_1" text="Ajouter les colonnes" />                                
    </div>

    <popo:listpanel dtcid="<%=ListeOuverteContributionDetailController.DTC_ELEMENTS_LISTE_OUVERTE%>" readonly="false">

        <popo:grid cols="2" colwidth="200px,*">
            <popo:iterator>
                <popo:field name="VALEUR"/>
                <popo:action name="DELETE_ELEMENT_LISTE_OUVERTE" text="<%=controller.getTextSupprimer()%>" style="icon"/>
            </popo:iterator>
        </popo:grid>
    </popo:listpanel>

    <div class="left">
        <popo:action name="ADD_ELEMENT_LISTE_OUVERTE" text="Ajouter un élément"/>   
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <%--<popo:link address="<%=AddressItems.IMPORT_LISTE_OUVERTE_ADDRESS.getAddress()%>" fields="CHAMP_ID" objects="<%="FOR_ID," + controller.getChampKey(champId)+","+controller.DTC_ELEMENTS_LISTE_OUVERTE%>" style="button">Importer</popo:link>--%>
        <popo:action name="IMPORT_LISTE_OUVERTE" text="Importer"/>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <popo:action name="EXPORT_LISTE_OUVERTE" text="Exporter" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="buttonbar">
        <div class="left">
            <popo:link address="<%=AddressItems.SECTION_CONTRIBUTION_DETAIL_ADDRESS.getAddress()%>" fields="SEC_ID" objects="FOR_ID" params="<%="MODE=" + DetailController.MODE_EDIT%>" style="button" confirm="<%=Constantes.MSG_CONFIRM_QUITTER_ECRAN_CREATION_MAJ%>">Abandonner</popo:link>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <popo:action name="SAVE_MODIFICATIONS_LISTE_OUVERTE" text="Enregistrer" isdefaultaction="true"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</popo:form>
```

Java method that will retrieve the ZONE variable to loop

```
public class ListeOuverteContributionDetailController extends AbstractContributionController {

    /**
     * Liste des éléments de la liste ouverte.
     */
    public static final String DTC_ELEMENTS_LISTE_OUVERTE = "DTC_ELEMENTS_LISTE_OUVERTE";
    public static final String SI_AJOUT_ELEMENT = "SI_AJOUT_ELEMENT";
    public static final String ZONE = "ZONE";

    public Message executeAddElementListeOuverte1() throws KUserException, KSystemException {

        final DtCollection<ElementListeOuverte> elementsListeOuverte = getContext().<ElementListeOuverte>getDtCollectionInput(DTC_ELEMENTS_LISTE_OUVERTE).validate();
        // la valeur zone qui doit être récupérée de la JSP
        final int zone = Integer.parseInt(getContext().getString(ZONE));
        for (int i = 1; i <= zone; i++) {
            // On ajoute un élément à la liste des éléments stockée dans le contexte en le flagant "Nouveau"
            final ElementListeOuverte elementListeOuverte = new ElementListeOuverte();
            final ChampContribution champ = getContext().<ChampContribution>getDtObjectInput(getChampKey(getContext().getLong(CHAMP_ID))).validate();
            elementListeOuverte.setChampId(champ.getChampId());
            elementListeOuverte.setSiNouveau(true);
            elementListeOuverte.setSiSupprime(false);
            elementsListeOuverte.add(elementListeOuverte);

            getContext().put(SI_AJOUT_ELEMENT, true);
        }
        return refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: For once, there is *too much* code in the question... In any case, you cannot pass values from JavaScript to JSP to Java (it's the other way around), what you *can* do is make an Ajax call from JavaScript.

Comment: I'm sorry for the whole code, 'cause I wanted to explain may prob. I'll edit it. In the JSP side, I've successed to get item value with the JS function getZoneJS(). Now I want to set it in a variable and submit it to the java method. I don't think AJAX will help me more.

Answer (score 4):

Set it as the value of a hidden input field which is enclosed in the form you'd like to submit.

As I have no idea what those `<popo:xxx>` tags represent/generate, they seem to be part of a custom tag library, I can't give a suitable answer. But it should basically end up to look like this:

```html
<form ...>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" id="foo" name="foo" />
</form>
```

which you can set as follows by JS:

```
document.getElementById("foo").value = yourNewValue;
```

it'll be available as a request parameter in the server side the usual way once the form is submitted:

```
String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
```

Comment: <popo:xxx> is a custom tag library. I get the iput values as var zone=(parseInt(document.form.elements["zone"].value)); and I want to set it on a variable JSP and use it in the context of my java method.

Comment: Yes, already guessed that. I don't recognize this name as one of the existing and well known tag libraries. If it's a custom library, you may not expect 1:1 support because nobody else is familiar with it. I have at least posted an answer which shows how to do it in standard JSP/JS/Servlet, so that you can apply the lessons learnt in your custom tag library. If you don't understand my answer at all, then it just stops here.

Comment: @frexville look for some `hidden input` like control in your toolkit and modify the code above accordingly.