# Javascript variable pass in Ruby on Rails method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to read out the value of a dropdown list and pass it to a ruby method. The result of my ruby method I want to use in a JavaScript framework.

My code looks as follows:

```
 var firstSelect = document.getElementById("firstLang");
 var firstOpt = firstSelect.options[firstSelect.selectedIndex].value;

 var curData = <%=raw BuildCompact.getData(firstOpt).to_json %>;
```

But that is not working because I cannot pass my JavaScript variable to my method. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you need to read about ajax

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a Javascript variable to server side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881686/how-to-send-a-javascript-variable-to-server-side)

Comment: Ruby runs on the server side, JavaScript runs on the client side.  The two simply cannot talk to each other this way.  Quentin's link is for Java, but the answer still applies; you need to do a remote request to the server to run Ruby code, either via a standard form submission or via AJAX.